# Making an object return its string when called

Tags: python

Best to explain with an example. I've defined a new class for a "point" object:

```
class point:

    def __init__(self, px, py):
        self.x = px
        self.y = py
        self.type = point

    def __str__(self):
        return "point(" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ")"
```

Now when I print a point all works well.

```
In [118]: p = point(2,5)

In [119]: print(p)
point(2, 5)
```

But being lazy I want the __str__ method to be returned when I just type p. Currently what I get is:

```
In [120]: p
Out[120]: <__main__.point at 0x1e446fffeb8>
```

while what I want is

```
In [120]: p
Out[120]: point(2, 5)
```

Is there a way to cause the __str__ to print by default when calling this type of object?

Comment: change `__str__` to `__repr__`.

Comment: You want `__repr__` instead. :-)

Comment: Yeh. Got it.  Simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the `__repr__` method.